# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier Value (include percent sign) Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign the value to variable in simple Java Script but getting `"unexpected identifier"` error, I feel that the`%` signs are creating problem here.

Any suggestion please?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to surround strings with quotes (`'` or `"`)

Comment: but the variable "token" is not surrounded with ' or " and it is working fine? actually I am getting these values from PHP variables and getting into JS.

Comment: They both need to be quoted

Comment: @aquariens I doubt it's working fine; it's trying to assign the value of a variable `a42...` (and so on) which presumably doesn't exits, so the value of `token` ends up as undefined.

Comment: var rid = <?php echo $GLOBALS['RID']; ?>; I will concatenate with quotes and get back to you to mark it answered.

Comment: @aquariens you really should use `json_encode()` instead of just tacking the quotes on yourself.

Answer (score 1):

the value you are assigning to the `rid` is string.

So, always use Quotes

`'`or`"`